# AngularJS : directive compiling to another parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Im trying to render directive's template into some other parent element.

The case is i have directive width config:

```
.directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'templates/some-template.html',
                controller: 'exportDetailsController',
                replace: false,
                link: link,
            }
})
```

usage:

```
<some-directive>link</someDirective>
```

And:

- i don't want directive element to be replaced by compiled template - this is achieved by:

  ```
  replace: false
  ```
- What i want is: after clicking 'link' text I want to compile template with some data and put the compiled content to some another place(in my case just display it in modal)

I was trying to use transclude, but this:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
   transclude(scope, function(clone) {
      console.log(clone);
   });
}
```

..logs me just empty text node (when i expected template data).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want your directive to put its content somewhere else, instead of just using the directive where you want it to be visible? You want your view code to actually contain itself, not to magically be fiddled with by something else.

Comment: Not understanding the objective here, or what the actual problem is Perhaps a demo would help

Comment: `templateUrl` is used to retrieve and compile/link the contents of the element that hosts the directive. If you just need "some HTML" to be a template - just store it in a variable and `$compile` it. Also, look into `$modal` (from angular-ui) about how to implement a modal